# App crashes when starting on iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

Today when testing app on iOS 5, I've found a problem, it crashes on starting.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivityViewController
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/6F884421-A676-434B-89E0-598F4F8F277F/HGroupware.app/HGroupware
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 in /var/mobile/Applications/6F884421-A676-434B-89E0-598F4F8F277F/HGroupware.app/HGroupware
```

So what should I do? Change deployment target to iOS >= 6.0 or any solution?
Please help me.

Comment: Personally, I think iOS 5 is a very tiny portion of the install base right now, so it shouldn't be worth supporting it... But your mileage may vary.

Comment: thank you... but my customers are still using iOS 5 ...

Comment: OK, then you will need to implement an alternative code path for iOS 5 (i.e., use something other that UIActivityViewController; perhaps roll ypur own...)

Comment: yes, I understand... the problem here is new tapku library. There're some UIActivityViewController was used. I'm trying to remove it. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** only solution is IOS >=6. Because `UIActivityViewController` is only available from **IOS6**. See this [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 3):

UIActivityViewController is "Available in iOS 6.0 and later.", so ideally, yes, change deployment target. Or change it on something else in code if [UIActivityViewController class] returns nil.